# How to count words in a string, using a set of positive and negative unigrams and bigrams?

Tags: r

I have strings of sentences, and a lists of bigrams and unigrams with words labelled positive (1), neutral (0) or negative (-1). I want to make four new variables that - for each string / sentence. The variables should give me a positivity score `pos`, negativity score `neg`, neutral score `neutral` and a variable that counts all words that aren't labelled `rest`. Logically, the `rest` variable can be made up by subtracting the total number of labelled words on `pos`, `neg` and `neutral` of the total number of the words of that sentence.

An addition: the score counters should first look in the list of bigrams. If a combination of words is found both in the string and on the list, and the score is -1, then it should counted for the total. After the bigrams, the code should do the same for the list of unigrams, but note that there are some words in bigrams, that also occur in the unigram list (e.g. `not good` and `good`). Therefore, I think it is best to replace the words by its corresponding value, and then count all replacements to make up the scores as variables.

I'd like to add that I made the example with bigrams and unigrams. If it is possible, I would like to have the option to also add a list of trigrams, but if this is not possible, then uni- and bigrams are also fine by me.

Here I have a data set. I also provided the desired result, which I computed by hand.

```
df <- data.frame(text = c("The food was fantastic. Such a nice restaurant", 
                          "Horrible. The ambience was not good", 
                          "A nice experience for me. I would recommend the chicken, it was simply delicious!",
                          "There was no place for us. Therefore, we had to wait very long, and the waitress forgot to write down our order"))
#List of bigrams with sentiment
Bigram <- c("not good", "no place", "very long", "simply delicious", "there was")
Sentiment <- c("-1", "-1", "-1", "1", "0")
df_bigram <- data.frame(Bigram, Sentiment)

#List of bigrams with sentiment
Unigram <- c("food", "fantastic", "nice", "horrible", "ambience", "experience", "wait", "waitress", "delicious", "good", "horrible")
Sentiment <- c("1", "1", "1", "-1", "0", "0", "-1", "0", "1", "1", "-1")
df_unigram <- data.frame(Unigram, Sentiment)

#Desired Outcome
df2 <- data.frame(text = c("The food was fantastic. Such a nice restaurant", 
                           "Horrible. The ambience was not good", 
                           "A nice experience for me. I would recommend the chicken, it was simply delicious!",
                           "There was no place for us. Therefore, we had to wait very long, and the waitress forgot to write down our order"),
                  pos = c("3", "0", "2", "0"),
                  neg = c("0", "2", "0", "2"),
                  neutral = c("0", "1", "1", "2"),
                  rest = c("5", "2", "10", "15"))
```

Comment: what have you tried so far ? I looks like you are asking for a complete solution of your problem. SO is not a free service website, it is a place to get help with your code when you are stuck. But it supposes that you do/try something, and not wait for the others to do everything for you

Comment: Sorry to not include that. I was thinking of splitting the list of unigrams and bigrams into 3 seperate lists, then use a gsub to replace specific parts of the sentence. To create the variables, I could use a conditional count that counts either -1s, 0s or 1s.

Comment: I've added an answer to the question at hand. I'm sure it could be more sophisticated, but in the end it worked. If someone sees parts that are overly clumpsy and can be easily coded shorter, let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

````
#Make copy of the text variable
df$text_copy <- df$text

#Clean the text
df$text <- tolower(df$text)

library(stringr)
df$text <- str_replace_all(df$text, "[^[:alnum:]]", " ")

#Make variable with number of words
df$nr_of_words <- sapply(strsplit(df$text, " "), length)

#Split the lists of uni- and bigrams
bigram_split_pos <- df_bigram[(df_bigram$Sentiment==1),]
bigram_split_neg <- df_bigram[(df_bigram$Sentiment==-1),]
bigram_split_neutral <- df_bigram[(df_bigram$Sentiment==0),]

unigram_split_pos <- df_unigram[(df_unigram$Sentiment==1),]
unigram_split_neg <- df_unigram[(df_unigram$Sentiment==-1),]
unigram_split_neutral <- df_unigram[(df_unigram$Sentiment==0),]

#Construct regular expressions
bigram_split_pos <- bigram_split_pos$Bigram
bigram_split_pos <- paste0("\\b(", paste0(bigram_split_pos, collapse="|"), ")\\b")    

bigram_split_neg <- bigram_split_neg$Bigram
bigram_split_neg <- paste0("\\b(", paste0(bigram_split_neg, collapse="|"), ")\\b")    

bigram_split_neutral <- bigram_split_neutral$Bigram
bigram_split_neutral <- paste0("\\b(", paste0(bigram_split_neutral, collapse="|"), ")\\b")    

unigram_split_pos <- unigram_split_pos$Unigram
unigram_split_pos <- paste0("\\b(", paste0(unigram_split_pos, collapse="|"), ")\\b")    

unigram_split_neg <- unigram_split_neg$Unigram
unigram_split_neg <- paste0("\\b(", paste0(unigram_split_neg, collapse="|"), ")\\b")    

unigram_split_neutral <- unigram_split_neutral$Unigram
unigram_split_neutral <- paste0("\\b(", paste0(unigram_split_neutral, collapse="|"), ")\\b")     


#Use the regular expressions with gsub
library(plyr)

df$text <- gsub(bigram_split_pos, "POS", df$text)
df$text <- gsub(bigram_split_neg, "NEG", df$text)
df$text <- gsub(bigram_split_neutral, "NEUTRAL", df$text)
df$text <- gsub(unigram_split_pos, "POS", df$text)
df$text <- gsub(unigram_split_neg, "NEG", df$text)
df$text <- gsub(unigram_split_neutral, "NEUTRAL", df$text)

#Make the variables using str_count
library(stringr)

df$pos <- str_count(df$text, "POS")
df$neg <- str_count(df$text, "NEG")
df$neutral <- str_count(df$text, "NEUTRAL")

rm(Bigram, Unigram, bigram_split_neg, bigram_split_neutral, bigram_split_pos,unigram_split_neg, unigram_split_neutral, unigram_split_pos, Sentiment)```

View(df)
````